# onPostExecute is not called in AsyncTask<Void, Void, Boolean> with abstract class

Tags: android, android-asynctask, abstract-class

i am working with Google Calendar API and stuck with AsyncTask. onPostExecute cannot be called if i use abstract class.

MakeRequestTask.java

```
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.util.Log;

import com.google.api.client.googleapis.extensions.android.gms.auth.GooglePlayServicesAvailabilityIOException;
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.extensions.android.gms.auth.UserRecoverableAuthIOException;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.List;

abstract class MakeRequestTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Boolean> {
private String TAG = "MakeRequestTask";

final MainActivity mainactivity;
final com.google.api.services.calendar.Calendar mService;
private Exception mLastError = null;

ProgressDialog loading = null;

//Calendar service;
MakeRequestTask(MainActivity mainactivity) {
    this.mainactivity = mainactivity;
    this.mService = mainactivity.mService;

    loading = new ProgressDialog(mainactivity);
    loading.setCancelable(true);
    loading.setMessage("Sync with Google Calendar";
    loading.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);

}

@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
    super.onPreExecute();
    Log.i(TAG, "onPreExecute");
    mainactivity.numAsyncTasks++;
    loading.show();
}


@Override
protected final Boolean doInBackground(Void... ignored) {
    Log.i(TAG, "doInBackground");
    try {
        doInBackground();
        return true;
    } catch (final GooglePlayServicesAvailabilityIOException availabilityException) {
        mainactivity.showGooglePlayServicesAvailabilityErrorDialog(
                availabilityException.getConnectionStatusCode());
    } catch (UserRecoverableAuthIOException userRecoverableException) {
        mainactivity.startActivityForResult(
                userRecoverableException.getIntent(), MainActivity.REQUEST_AUTHORIZATION);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        //Utils.logAndShow(activity, MainActivity.TAG, e);
        Log.i(TAG, "IOException" + e);
    }
    return false;
}

@Override
protected final void onPostExecute(Boolean success) {
    super.onPostExecute(success);
    Log.i(TAG, "onPostExecute");
    loading.cancel();
    if (0 == --mainactivity.numAsyncTasks) {
    }
    if (success) {
    }
}


abstract protected void doInBackground() throws IOException;

}
```

AsyncLoadEvent.java (one of the abstract class)

```
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.preference.PreferenceManager;
import android.util.Log;

import com.google.api.client.util.DateTime;
import com.google.api.services.calendar.model.Event;
import com.google.api.services.calendar.model.Events;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

class AsyncLoadEvent extends MakeRequestTask {
private String TAG = "AsyncLoadEvent";

AsyncLoadEvent(MainActivity mainActivity) {
    super(mainActivity);
    this.mainActivity = mainActivity;
}

@Override
protected void doInBackground() throws IOException {
    Log.i(TAG, "doInBackground");
    try {
        ......
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.i(TAG, "Exception" + e);
        cancel(true);
    }
}
}
```

As you can see from this question, if i do not use abstract class and change the AsyncTask java to as follows, onPostExecute will be called.

```
...
@Override
protected final Boolean doInBackground(Void... ignored) {
    Log.i(TAG, "doInBackground");
    return true;
}
...
```

I am really appreciate if anyone could point out any mistake in my code, even duplicate solution will be nice, as long as providing a clear explanation or guide.

if you want more code in my abstract class, i will do so.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, i have found the issue after some work around. it was related to my abstract class.

AsyncLoadEvent.java (one of the abstract class)

```
@Override
protected void doInBackground() throws IOException {
    Log.i(TAG, "doInBackground");
    try {
        getDataFromApi();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.i(TAG, "Exception : " + e);
        cancel(true);
        Log.i(TAG, "cancel(true)");
    }
}
```

The class was jumped into Exception and run "cancel(true)" because i tried to update UI components in "getDataFromApi()", and it then wouldn't call onPostExecute().

i seeked into Override method in AsyncTask class and found onCancelled() is available. And saw a [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11324049/7615260) says:

> Calling this method will result in onCancelled(Object) being invoked
>   on the UI thread after doInBackground(Object[]) returns. Calling this
>   method guarantees that onPostExecute(Object) is never invoked. After
>   invoking this method, you should check the value returned by
>   isCancelled() periodically from doInBackground(Object[]) to finish the
>   task as early as possible.